# How can i assert value which is dynamically generated in selenium webdriver using c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver

I have generated dynamic value and i want to verify the value using 'assert'.
can you please advice me.

This is my code:i want  verify job title  in job 1

```html
 Random jobtitle = new Random();
string jobtitle1 = string.Format("CVviaATS{0}_{1}", jobtitle.Next(2, 40).ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmm"));
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MiddleContent_EditJob1_EditJob1_VacTitle")).SendKeys(jobtitle1);//Generate random value for Job Title//

 IWebElement job1 = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("jdtitle"));
            Assert.IsTrue(jobtitle.);
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to assert ? that the value was set to the element with that id? You've just set it, that would be testing that WebDriver works, doesn't sound very useful for you.

Comment: Actually i have created job title having dynamic value.Then after that i want to assert that value (i mean title ) which is reflected on different different id.

Comment: Ok so use the same drive.FindElement(By.Id(.... to find that element and check its value: element.GetAttribute("value") or whatever attribute that value was set on.

Comment: Awesome ! That's working! Thank you.

Comment: OK, added that as an answer, please mark it as the correct one so that everyone can see it. You're welcome!

Comment: Sorry ! It is not working,it was picking wrong item. IWebElement job1 = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("jdtitle"));
            Assert.IsTrue(job1.GetAttribute("jobtitle1"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
iWebElement job1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//a[contains(., '{0}')]", jobtitle1)));
```

iWebElement job1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//a[contains(., '{0}')]", jobtitle1)));

As per zahed ,i have just modified selector.and its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If I am following you correctly I think you can use something like:

```
Assert.IsTrue(job1.Contains(jobtitle));
```

If you have upper/lower case issues you could also just compare it to lower:

```
Assert.IsTrue(job1.ToLower().Contains(jobtitle.ToLower()));
```

Comment: i didn't use  assert IWebElement job1 = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("jdtitle"));
            job1.GetAttribute("vactitle");
            job1.Click();

Comment: Should i use any references ??i unable to add 'ToLower'

Comment: Sorry i have that library.but still its not coming though

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `drive.FindElement(By.Id(....` to find that element and check its value: `element.GetAttribute("value")` or whatever attribute that value was set on

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo,that was quite helpful and working .